# Android back button with web view functionality not working properly

Tags: android, webview

Hi I am developing android application in which I am using one web view. My web view has some data which redirect to some different link. So when I click it should come back to previous content. And finally it should close the web view when it comes to landing page. I tried it in following ways :

```
webView = new WebView(this);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.contains(URLManager.URL_DICOM_BACK_PRESSED_URL)) {

                processBackPressed();
                return true;
            } else {

                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            if (failingUrl.contains(URLManager.URL_DICOM_BACK_PRESSED_URL)) {
                processBackPressed();
            } else {
                showError("Server unreachable");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (webView != null && webView.canGoBack()) {          

        webView.goBack();
    } else {            

        processBackPressed();
    }
}
```

So problem is that whenever it is coming back to previous page it is fist showing current page and then previous page.So looks like first refresh the page and then load previous url. Am I doing anything wrong. Need Some Help. Thank you.

Comment: try with finish() instead of using back pressed ?

Comment: off-topic: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.* what processBackPressed does? also how exactly looks the page transition(fx when URL_DICOM_BACK_PRESSED_URL is hitted)? ... with such little information(especially without "not working properly" definition) only you can resolve your problem ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if(myWebView.canGoBack()){
                myWebView.goBack();
            }else{
                finish();
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```